# What does LAST_CR_BUFFER_GETS mean, in Oracle SQL Developer Autotrace

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Please explain the meaning and significance of the column 'LAST_CR_BUFFER_GETS', shown in the Oracle SQL Developer Autotrace view.

Comment: That is probably the information from `V$SQL_PLAN_STATISTICS`: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/dynviews_3056.htm#REFRN30251

Comment: Ok, great! Google couldn't find that page for me.
Put this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As answered in the comments by @a_horse_with_no_name, per [this Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/dynviews_3052.htm#REFRN30251) it is:

> Number of buffers retrieved in consistent mode

The word 'consistent' is used as a technical term, contrasted with 'current'; "Buffers are usually retrieved in consistent mode for queries." and "Buffers are retrieved in current mode for statements such as INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE."  So this information tells you how much data your SQL caused Oracle to move around for each type of work.